# Check if is null JasperReports

Tags: jasper-reports

I have the following problem with JasperReports , I receive the content correctly , however when the content is null i am interesting to not showing nothing.

Could anyone help to me?

```
<textField>
    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
    <box leftPadding="10"/>
    <textElement/>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{nombre}]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set "blank when null" checkbox at property of field

[image]

After that definition text filed in jrxml like this:

```
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
            ....
            <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font fontName="DejaVu Sans" size="12"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{leftColumn}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
```

Comment: I am using a template .jrxml

Comment: Thanks for your answer :D